# issue with iAds in production

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, iad

I have an approved app in the Apple app store. I programmed iAds funcitonality on several screens. It works fine in the development version. obviously iAds show up as a dummy there.

The issue is that the app got approved by Apple yesterday: Naggy, as free app. But iAds are not showing up at all.

Any clues? Could it be that I forgot to set something up in the Itunes connect? I did sign-up for iAds (contract and bank account are set).

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you enable iAds for the app itself? Select the app and click the 'Set Up iAd Network' button.

Comment: I tried doing that but it said thet the app was in an uneditable state. How do I change state?

Comment: Maybe you have to create a new version in order to make it editable.

Comment: Absolutely, you can only change the iAd state when you're updating the App with a new version.